# Align JMenuItem text regardless of whether or not an ImageIcon is used

Tags: java, swing

I have a Menu that when I have an ImageIcon on the menu, it move the text to the right. I would like it to always move the text to the right regardless of whether or not there is an ImageIcon used for the menu.

I have tried setting the horizontal alignment.

[image: MenuWithAndWithoutImageIcon]

You can see what is happening in the attached image. I am using the following code (ignore the horizontal alignment as I was testing )

```
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(childmenu.getProperty(MenuDef.text()));
            menuItem.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
            menuItem.setToolTipText(childmenu.getProperty(MenuDef.tooltip()));
            String image = childmenu.getProperty(MenuDef.image());
            HIcon icon = ThinClient.iconManager().getIcon(image);
            if(icon!=null)
                menuItem.setIcon(icon.getIcon());
```

Some menus will have images and some will not but I don't want the text alignment to look bad.

Comment: Create a blank icon

Comment: Perfect thanks! I just added a screenshot and the code I used for a blank icon. Perfect solution.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0):

After the suggestion by madprogrammer below is the result

[image]

I used the following code for a blank icon:

```
public static Icon BlankIcon(int size) {
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    return new ImageIcon(image);
}
```

THANKS AGAIN!